# VirtualBox no Internet in headless mode only

Tags: macos, virtualbox, headless

I have Windows 10 in a VirtualBox. When I run it from within VirtualBox everything works fine. The network is in a bridged mode and Guest system has Internet access.

However, when I run it in a headless mode, there is no Internet connection from withing the Guset system (Windows 10). Actually there is no network communication from Guest to Host. Guest system gets IP address, but I can't ping Host IP. And I can't renew IP of the Guest machine. It looks like the IP is cached because if I release it I can't get it back.
The host machine is MacOS.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the output of `ipconfig /renew` ?

Comment: `ipconfig /renew` gives "Connection timeout"